# How to permanently remove moisture on concrete kitchen floor

Tags: kitchens, moisture, vinyl-flooring, sealant

[image][image]We are currently renovating our kitchen and when we removed our vinyl flooring we noticed lot of moisture. We want to put self adhesive vinyl tiles but wanted to avoid the scenario of moisture creeping it again. We have checked and there is no leakage so this must be the moisture from the condensation. We have attached some pictures and i have already switched on the dehumidifier. We are in the Uk and any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify if moisture is wicking up from the ground tape a large square of plastic to the floor for 24 hours, when you peel the plastic up if the plastic is wet and or the floor it is coming from below. The only way I have had any luck drying out a wet slab is to wait till later in the summer and use a 2 part epoxy paint, I have had good results sealing basements and below grade slabs using this method. After that any type of flooring can be used. The one issue I see is the floor is going to require a lot more cleaning, I have rented a shot blaster several times this is like a sand blaster but it uses lead shot and it really strips down to the concrete leaving the concrete a bit rough but that is perfect as the epoxy paint really adheres well and will leave a smooth surface. Note a trash bag is something most people have that can be taped down, be careful when pulling it up and you can use it for the trash.